# Why does next.js work so slowly in faced 'Indexing'?

Tags: webstorm, next.js

I have worked in 'webstorm IDE', window 10, 8gb ram, i5 cpu.

But, When Webstorm have proceeded 'Indexing(please look down the picture)', My computer always worked so slowly

This is why???

[image]

Comment: Indexing is indeed very resource-intensive and might utilize all your CPU cores, so it can cause the overall system slowdown on computers that aren't powerful enough. But it is normally only performed on project opening/switching VCS branches (and on massive changes made to project folders - for example, on generating files, that's why we strongly recommend to exclude build destination directories from project)

If you face issue with constant project re-indexing while editing your code, this is likely a bug that has to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to ignore certain folders from indexing, such as the `.next` folder. [This answer](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000527504-Prevent-folder-from-being-indexed?page=1#community_comment_115000444210) mentions that you can right click on a folder in Webstorm and click "Exclude from Index"

Comment: Thank you for youer advie. But, In my webstorm, There are no buttom 'Exclude from index' when i had clicked right click on a folder such as .next......

Answer (score 0):

In Webstorm:

In your project explorer on the left - right click the directory > mark directory as > excluded